# Detecting a change in another application

Tags: android, ios

I'm working on a personal project as a learning experience and I need to know if it is possible to programmatically detect a change in another application. For instance if a button was added/made visible/clickable  at random intervals  and locations in the second app, 
the first app would be able to detect the change in the second app; click it and  tally it
and the second app would also tally every time the button was made visible to compare how accurate the first app is.

As I searched Google, Stack Overflow and the Android Developer training site, I couldn't find an answer.

**TLDR;**

1. App one opens App two
2. App one refreshes App two, checking for changes, i.e a button being added
3. App one clicks the button, both apps tally the buttons

Comment: There's options if both apps are yours, but if not then its not possible.

Comment: take a look at `http://appium.io/`. Not sure this is exactly what you need but can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is not generally possible. Apps cannot spy on other apps this way. One exception is an `AccessibilityService`, but I do not know if it covers your use case.